# Runwheel function in html

Tags: javascript

I recently came across this code and was wondering what it actually does and what the output is.

```
function runwheel() {
    tid=tid+1
}
```

Comment: It's an increment. It's pretty simple. Assume `tid` = 1. call `runwheel()`, `tid` is now 2. Run it again, 3. 4. 5. etc. Also can be expressed as `tid++` (see post increment operator). Please read some JavaScript tutorials, this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: *"and what the output is"* - There is no output, unless you count the fact that that function returns `undefined` as a type of output.

Comment: @nnnnnn `typeof undefined` is `"undefined"`, not `output` ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is an incrementer function. The variable `tid`, which is defined elsewhere, is being used to track something. Every time `runwheel` is called, that value is increased by one. This could be used to track every time a particular event happens by making `runwheel` a handler for that event.

Comment: I'm not saying don't answer these questions, it's not my place to tell you what to do, and I won't downvote because you're right (some downvote here), but this question is JavaScript 101 and should be closed and commented on with resources.

Answer (score 0):

It will increments the tid variable by 1 every time this function is called. the better way to increment a variable by only **1** is the below code:

```js
let total = 0;

const increment = () =>{
  total++
}
```